# Вывод экземпляра пользовательского класса в ListView

Tags: java, javafx

Допустим у меня есть класс:

```
public class Person{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    //все остальное
}
```

Мне нужно, что бы в ListView были поля name и age. Но когда я выбираю в ListView элемент надо иметь возможность получить id.

Имена могут совпадать.
Как это сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вывести тебе объект класа `Person` в лист вью, необходимо :

1. Параметризировать `ListView<Person>`
2. Проставить свою `cellFactory` для данной ListView, в котором необходимо переопределить метод `updateItem(Person item, boolean empty)`. Самой простой реализацией будет следующующая реализация

ListView listView = new ListView<>();

```
        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Person>, ListCell<Person>>()
        {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Person> call(ListView<Person> param)
            {
                return new ListCell<Person>(){
                    protected void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty)
                    {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null && !empty)
                        {
                            setText(item.getName() + " " + item.getAge());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            setText(null);
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```

3. в `if (item != null && !empty)` можно выставить любое свое отображение, которое только позволит воображение.
4. Когда происходи выбор элемента в данном `listView`, вернется объект класса `Person`, с которым можно взаимодействовать